# Android converting from LinearLayout to CheckedTextView and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have customized my own `ListView`, which consists of:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_lan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:textSize="25sp" /></LinearLayout>
```

and i want to be able to show what text is inside my `CheckedTextView`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (((TextView)CheckedTextView)view).getText().ToString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So as I assume, view contains reference to my `LinearLayout`. How to access the text in `CheckedTextView`? Because my way doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

     CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
        // do anything to checkedTextView now 
        checkedTextView.toggle();

                    }
```

see how the param `arg1` is used and this should work!

Answer (score 0):

The `view` parameter holds a view what is created by the adapter, and it is supposed to contain your custom layout too ([see reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)).
So you can get the text of your (Checked)TextView this way:

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_lan)).getText().toString()
```